# Using 2D Array for Tic Tac Toe in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I have to make a tic tac toe game for my Visual Basic class that uses an array to keep track of the state of the game, but I have no idea how to set up this array. The program is supposed to have 2 views (a GUI which I have already done, and a text view using the console which I have no idea how to do), has two controllers (the user can click the button where they want to play, or they can use the keys 1-9 on the keyboard to choose their position), and is to be played between a human and the computer.

It's not much, but here's what I have so far:

```
  Module Module1
Const intMAX_ROWS As Integer = 2
Const intMAX_COL As Integer = 2
Public gameArray(intMAX_ROWS, intMAX_COL) As String

Button1.Text = gameArray(0,0) 
Button2.Text = gameArray(0,1)
Button3.Text = gameArray(0,2)
Button4.Text = gameArray(1,0)
Button5.Text = gameArray(1,1)
Button6.Text = gameArray(1,2)
Button7.Text = gameArray(2,0)
Button8.Text = gameArray(2,1)
Button9.Text = gameArray(2,2)

End Module
```

I am getting an error on all of the Button.Text lines saying

```
Declaration expected
```

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the program to compile the statements where you assign values to buttons need to be inside a function:

```
Sub SetButtons()
    Button1.Text = gameArray(0, 0)
    Button2.Text = gameArray(0, 1)
    Button3.Text = gameArray(0, 2)
    Button4.Text = gameArray(1, 0)
    Button5.Text = gameArray(1, 1)
    Button6.Text = gameArray(1, 2)
    Button7.Text = gameArray(2, 0)
    Button8.Text = gameArray(2, 1)
    Button9.Text = gameArray(2, 2)
End Sub
```

As you need 2 views, a GUI and a text view, I'd recommend ending up with 3 projects:

- a TicTacToe library for the game logic (to be shared)
- a WinForms or WPF application for the GUI view (that references the library)
- a Console application for the text view (that references the library)

Here's an example of drawing a board in a console application:

```
Dim board(3, 3) As Char
' Set a O in the middle
board(1, 1) = "O"
' Set an X at the bottom right
board(2, 2) = "X"
' Show board
Console.WriteLine(board(0, 0) + "|" + board(1, 0) + "|" + board(2, 0))
Console.WriteLine("-----")
Console.WriteLine(board(0, 1) + "|" + board(1, 1) + "|" + board(2, 1))
Console.WriteLine("-----")
Console.WriteLine(board(0, 2) + "|" + board(1, 2) + "|" + board(2, 2))
```

which gives:

```
 | |
-----
 |O|
-----
 | |X
```

For a little inspiration on the GUI side, here's a short Silverlight sample (written in [F#](http://www.trelford.com/blog/post/fs4vb.aspx)): [Tic-Tac-Toe](http://trelford.com/blog/post/Tic-tac-toe.aspx)